# PostgreSQL 9.6 w/ pgAdmin 4: unable to backup database (missing pg_dump, pg_restore)

Tags: windows, backup, database-backups, postgresql-9.6, pgadmin-4

When I try to backup my PostgreSQL database in pgAdmin4, the process fails with exit code 1, stating that 'pg_dump.exe' is not recognized.

Under 'Preferences > Paths', I specified 'C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin' as the PostgreSQL Binary Path. However, it appears that pg_dump is not present in this or any other directory.

What might I be able to do in order to create this backup? Your advice will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to find pg_dump binary with my installation at

> 'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin'

How did you install PostgresSQL & pgAdmin4?

Comment: I downloaded it from here: [link](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads#windows)

Comment: Then try copy pasting path as the PostgreSQL Binary Path which I provided :)